# Symbol of computer science

Tags: computer-science, symbols

I'm programming a Website and wanted to include the symbol of computer science, but i couldn't find the symbol somewhere ...

does someone know where i can find it? Do we have a symbol?

for example psychology has a symobl:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychology

Comment: http://images.google.com/images?hl=en&biw=1680&bih=935&tbs=isch:1&sa=1&q=computer+science+logo&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

Comment: this might be the problem there are very much logos, but i'm looking for THAT symbol, like the symbol of psychology i posted.

Comment: The "symbol of psychology" you have there is a capital Greek letter psi, which is to say it's an initial not some mystical symbol.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go with Greek letters then probably **ϴ** would be a good choice. Or perhaps just a Roman "Big O": **O** ?

Comment: For reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: I tend to agree with your suggestion in that Algorithms are the life of computer science and computers themselves are like magic papers enacting those algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

People often put 0 and 1 in rows.
http://www.google.com/images?q=computer+science&biw=1366&bih=636